# How to lock Files to avoid deletion using NIO package

Tags: java, windows, nio

I am using NIO File Channel to manage files, and locking them.  So far it works, however when I lock a File using NIO File Lock it locks the file so the file Content cannot be changed. As for example if I try to edit a text file on notepad it will show me the following error message:
[image: File Lock]

And that is the expected result, however if I try to delete the file from windows explorer(I haven't tested on other OS likely will be possible as well) it will allow me, and this is undesired, I would like to know if it is possible to Open a File Handle

Code Used:

```
private static final byte[] MessageBytes;
static {
    byte tmp[];
    try {
        tmp = "Hello World".getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        //if fail get the bytes in whatever the java VM charset sets as default
        tmp = "Hello World".getBytes();
    }
    MessageBytes = tmp;
}
private static final String Filename = "Lock_test.txt";

 private static void createFileandLock() {
    Path FilePath = Paths.get(Filename);
    FileChannel OpenFCh;
    try {
        OpenFCh = FileChannel.open(FilePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE
        //                    ,StandardOpenOption.APPEND
        );
        System.out.println("File Channel is Open.");
    } catch (IOException err) {
        OpenFCh = null;
    }
    if (OpenFCh != null) {
        FileLock Lock = null;
        try {
            Lock = OpenFCh.lock();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println("Unable To Lock the File.");
        }
        try {
            OpenFCh.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(MessageBytes));
            OpenFCh.force(false);
            System.out.println("Message Recorded");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable To write data into file");
        }
        try {
            // at this point file still locked and open.
            //lets wait for input and meanwhile ask to delete the file. 
            System.out.print("Please Try to delete file at: ");
            System.out.println(FilePath.toString());
            System.out.println("Press Enter to Continue");
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if (Lock != null) {
            try {
                Lock.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
        try {
            OpenFCh.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

After further research I notice that using [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) Will lock the file avoiding deletion as it creates a  [File Descriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) that basically open a Handle on the underline Operative system. 
So using the RAF does provide the desired result: 
[image: File Open Message]

Code Used:

```
private static void createRAFileandLock() {
    RandomAccessFile RAf;
    try {
        RAf = new RandomAccessFile(Filename, "rw");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        //since is open as RW shold not trigger.
        RAf = null;
    }
    if (RAf != null) {
        FileChannel OpenFCh = RAf.getChannel();
        FileLock Lock = null;
        try {
            Lock = OpenFCh.lock();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println("Unable To Lock the File.");
        }
        try {
            OpenFCh.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(MessageBytes));
            OpenFCh.force(false);
            System.out.println("Message Recorded");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable To write data into file");
        }
         // at this point file still locked and open.
        //lets wait for input and meanwhile ask to delete the file. 
        try {
            System.out.print("Please Try to delete file at: ");
            System.out.println(Filename);
            System.out.println("Press Enter to Continue");
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if (Lock != null) {
            try {
                Lock.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
        try {
            OpenFCh.close();
            RAf.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

However I would like to know if it is possible to archive this using only NIO. As Random Access File is on IO package.

Comment: just out of curiosity: what is the problem with using a class that is found in IO package?

Comment: there is no problem, however i would like to avoid using(and or Importing) Other package besides NIO.
Using 'FileChannel.open' open the file channel and using this class also can provide me a lock, however missing the option to open a handle with a 'FileDescriptor' so is more about if is possible to do using only nio, or if is possible to code so it open a handle and avoid a user or other application from deleting the file, other than using RAF or any class within IO package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FileLock isn't specified to prevent deletion. It's only specified to interact with other file locks, so you're already deep into platform-dependent behaviour. If RandomAccessFile somehow does what you want you may be stuck with it, but you can't rely on it.

NB of course FileChannel.open() uses a FileDescriptor, handle, etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer.

I am aware that FileLock will not prevent deletion. but it was used as it also provide a wanted feature and behavior.


I fear as much, that there might no be way around this, however is there a option to ensure the FileDescriptor or a handle keep the File "Open" to ensure the file cannot be deleted?, Also hoped that maybe a Special Open Option could be use on this case... hmm maybe I should request as a new feature for JRE? as it might prove to be useful.

Comment: There is nothing except platform dependence that says an open file can't be deleted  in the first place, so it has nothing to do with any API implementation in any language. Every system derived from Unix permits it. So you quest is ill-formed before it starts

Comment: Not everyone using Java cares about crossplatform behavior.

Comment: @NateS It's not just about cross-latform behaviour. *The plaform the OP is presently running on* may not support what he wants.